# Do generics do boxing / unboxing when I keep Object type to the collection

Tags: c#

If I have a list that holds the `Object` in it like this:

```
List<object> t = new List<object>();
t.Add(10);
t.Add("xyx");
```

in this case if I fetch back the list items do I need to unbox them?

Comment: *You* are asking *us*? It depends on what you 're going to do with them.

Comment: I am asking this because most artical say it overcome boxing unboxing concept that was there in collections, although they do not specify if you are making it hold object then you need to box unbox it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Unboxing" only occurs if you have used an object to hold a value type.

In your example, the `t.Add(10);` is indeed boxing an int value type as an object, so it will have to be unboxed when you access it.

However, the `t.Add("xyx");` is adding a string reference type, so it will NOT be boxed and it will NOT need to be unboxed when you access it.

In both cases, however, you must *cast* the value to the correct type in order to access it as that type.

Answer (score 3):

if you need treat them like objects of *specific* type, yes.

```
var o = t[0]; //this is object
var i = (int)t[0]; //this is int
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If you want to use it as that specific type then yes. Else you can just use them as objects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to unbox them to specific type.